# Constructors with arguments and the admin page

Tags: django

I have a class `Foo` with two fields: an integer field `x`, and a comma-separated integer field `n`. The value of `n` represents the number of elements in `x`. When I create an instance of this class, I want to set `x` to a set of `n` zeroes, each separated by a comma.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    x = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length = 100)

    def __init__(self, _n):
        super(User, self).__init__()
        self.n = _n
        self.x = [0,] * _n
```

This seems to work fine to construct instances of `Foo`. However, when I log in as admin and click on one of the `Foo` instances, it gives me the error: `__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)`

My interpretation of this is that admin is trying to create an instance of `Foo` when I ask to view it, without supplying the necessary arguments (although I don't know where the `4 given` comes from). So my question is: **How should I be writing Python constructors with arguments, such that the instances can also be displayed in the admin page?**

One alternative I can think of is to leave the default constructor, and write `f = Foo(n = 5)` when I create an instance. However, how can I then run the line `self.x = [0,] * _n` by default without having to write it as a separate function, to call whenever I create an instance?

Comment: First, read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects You should not override method signature. Try with `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` and then get your value from `kwargs`

Answer (score 2):

As Germano pointed out in the comments, you should read the [documentation on this subject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects).

You can't really override `__init__` as the admin expects a certain interface. You have a couple of alternatives. Here I'll adapt the docs to your example.

Add a `classmethod`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    x = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length = 100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, n):
        f = cls(n=n)
        f.x = # whatever
        return f

f = Foo.create(42)
```

Use a method on a Foo manager:

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def create_foo(self, n):
        f= self.create(n=n)
        f.x = # something
        return f

class Foo(models.Model):
    n = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    x = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length = 100)

    objects = FooManager()

f = Foo.objects.create_foo(42)
```

You really don't want to override `__init__` because you can't really tell if your code is calling it, or some other part of Django (like the admin). If Django is creating a `Foo` object with `n` and `x` values from the database, you don't want to set your own value of `x`, you want to use the value from the database. I suppose you could check to see if `n` is supplied and not `x`, but it is really safer and more clear to just create your own "constructor" type methods as above.

Comment: As the OP asked that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556655/converting-comma-separated-string-to-list I think he should mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Germano he might have marked it accepted right in the middle of me making an edit. I thought I saw a green check mark briefly. He might have to do it again.